# How do I evaluate paths like Property1.Property2 into compiled Expression without Roslyn

Tags: c#, eval, blazor-webassembly

In my blazor webassembly app I would like to evaluate string paths like:

- `"Property1.Property2"`
- optionally `Property1[index]` and `Property1["key"]`
- optionally `Method1().Property2`

The requirements are:

1. I'm able to compile/cache the expression somehow and evaluate it multiple times with different parameter (parameter = source object). Speed is important
2. I need to evaluate the path in order to get value
3. I need to be able to set value if the path points to a property.
4. I need to be able to get the MemberInfo, although this could be done externally using different evaluator.

I do not need to evaluate mathematical expression like <s>`Property1 * Property2`</s>

### What do I have

I have used RoslynAPI, simmilar to this:

```
var discountFilter = "album => album.Quantity > 0";
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(typeof(Album).Assembly);
 
Func<Album, bool> discountFilterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<Album, bool>>(discountFilter, options);
 
var discountedAlbums = albums.Where(discountFilterExpression)
```

but I cannot use Roslyn in my Blazor WebAssembly apps, because it it too heavy.

Is there a more lightweight way of evaluating paths, that preferably builds expressions?

Comment: They look close to the `PropertyPaths` used in WPF bindings, but presumably that's not going to fly in Blazor either...

Comment: How about sending the expression string to server side and have it processed there?

Comment: I don't know that there's anything else built-in, but it probably wouldn't be too hard to parse those sorts of string paths and construct Expressions from them

Comment: I don't know that there's anything else built-in, but it probably wouldn't be too hard to parse those sorts of string paths and construct Expressions from them

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it for WASM specifically, but expression trees may be your friend here - however, there is no magic "parse this string" button for this; but assuming you have your own parser for the string, you would be looking to end up inspecting the AST and constructing an `Expression` similar to:

```cs
// constructs: (Album album) => album.Quantity > 0
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Album), "album");
var body = Expression.GreaterThan(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(p, "Quantity"),
    Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int)));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Album, bool>>(body, p);
```

Then you can get your reusable delegate via:

```cs
Func<Album, bool> func = lambda.Compile();
```

In terms of setting a value: that's fine too: `Expression.Assign` inside an `Expression.Block`, which can again be compiled.

However! On WASM, I *suspect* that `Compile()` is going to use interpretation rather than ref-emit, which means it *might* just be using reflection (`PropertyInfo.SetValue` etc) under the hood, rather than anything more native.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I would like to go, but I'm looking for the parser that would generate the expression three. 
Also, building the expression is much more complicated, when the input and output times are not know at compile time Expression.Lambda<Func<??, ??>>(body, p);

Comment: @Liero re generics: there is a non-generic API too - just take away the `<...>`; this gives you just `Delegate` rather than a more-specifically typed one, and you can use `DynamicInvoke`; on the parse step, yes, that's a gap in the out-of-the-box experience; there may be pre-existing parsers, I don't know.